# How to make AutoMapper throw when mapping null into non-nullable value type?

Tags: automapper

I have two classes:

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(int? value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int? Value { get; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; }
}
```

When mapping an instance of `ClassA` with `Value == null` into `ClassB`, AutoMapper seems to ignore the property and provide the default value instead:

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>();
});
var mapper = new Mapper(config);

var classA = new ClassA(null);
var classB = mapper.Map<ClassB>(classA);

Debug.Assert(classB.Value == 0);
```

How do I make AutoMapper throw an exception when mapping an instance of `ClassA` with `Value == null` into `ClassB` instead? Optimally, **can I enable this behavior for all mappings from nullable value types to non-nullable value types?**

Comment: You can create a map from `int?` to `int`. Or, more advanced, [a simple object mapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/eafff201494a6aa3cd07159048f4722ec7509d16/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L93).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, adding a map from `int?` to `int` works, but isn't generic, and requires adding such a map for each value type I want the behavior for. (I've added an answer below regardless.)

Could you add an answer that shows how an `ObjectMapper` might solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I can add a custom `BeforeMap` function that tries to identify these kind of situations via reflection, but I'd prefer a simpler solution and/or one that also handled custom mappings of differently named properties, etc.

```cs
cfg.ForAllMaps((_, e) => e.BeforeMap(CheckForDisallowedNulls));

void CheckForDisallowedNulls(object source, object destination)
{
    foreach (var sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(sourceProperty.PropertyType);
        if (underlyingType is { })
        {
            var destinationProperty = destination.GetType().GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);
            if (destinationProperty is { } && destinationProperty.PropertyType == underlyingType && sourceProperty.GetValue(source) == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(sourceProperty.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can create a map from `int?` to `int` that throws an exception when the source value is null:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<int?, int>().ConvertUsing((s, _) => s.Value);
```

However, this requires adding such a map for each nullable value type I want the behavior for.